# IBM Infosphere Data Flow designer Server Access is denied when starting

Tags: windows, datastage, ibm-infosphere

I installed Infosphere Information server 11.7.1 Information Server on a Windows 2019. All the services for Infosphere and DB2 started in when I check the Window Services. However, when I log into the server as admin, a console appear The message on the console is:

```
No instance(s) available 
D:\IBM|InformaqtionServer\ASBNode\....
Starting DataStage Floe Designer.... Access is denied
Starting DataStage Floe Designer.... Access is denied
Starting DataStage Floe Designer.... Access is denied
```

I started Infosphere Launchpad and everything looks normal. What is this error and how do I resolve it?
I have checked the logs in ASBNode Lofs and ASB Server logs but cannot see any issues.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting full rights to all users recursively for directory ..\ASBNode\CognitiveDesignerEngine, it looks like you might have a user rights issue/conflict between the user which started the service and the one you are trying to start the DFD with.

Note: I don't think Windows 2019 has been qualified yet for Information Server 11.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have to try that when we get back to the work site. It's a lockdown here and we have no access to the servers. I have installed on fresh Windows server and I didn't get that error. So, I suspect it's something on the Windows policy setting on their server.

Comment: Sorry for the delays, what I found is that everytime I log in, the system will launch startCognitiveDesignerServer.bat. I had to manually run this As an Administrator and the designer will start without error. 

I am trying go see how I can configure to run as elevated command automatically.